# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de fondo de un Button mediante codigo?

Tags: java, android

Cuando le doy click, el boton se deshabilita mediante:

```
btnmyButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que cuando le dé click cambie de fondo para resaltar el efecto.

Comment: agrega el código que has realizado por favor. Define que es lo que deseas, cuando das clic nuevamente cambias de color pero el botón se mantiene deshabilitado?

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir este "efecto" puedes realizar lo siguiente:

```
btnmyButton.setEnabled(false);
btnMyButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#9E9E9E"));
```

se vera asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y habilitado el boton :

```
btnmyButton.setEnabled(true);
btnmyButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

se vera asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes notar al momento de estar desabilitado el texto donde dice **comenzar** cambia de color. puedes cambiar el texto o el fondo del color del botón, pero en términos de diseño es mas conveniente cambiar el texto.

Por otro lado si no deseas cambiar el texto del boton y si el fondo del boton, solo debes usar : `MyButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.blue);`

Si deseas mas revisar los colores que tiene Android Studio, los puedes ver en su [pagina oficial](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-palette), podras ver una gama completa.

***NOTA: AHORA LA LÓGICA DE CUANDO DESEAS HABILITAR Y DESABILITAR TU BOTÓN DEPENDERÁ DE TU CÓDIGO.***

Comment: Gracias #Ashley G.

Comment: @RiouriSatsumoto que bueno, que te haya servido, no olvides dar por correcta la respuesta, saludos

Comment: si, ok ahorita lo pienso probar, pero ya lo revise y lo mas seguro que es correcto pero mi deber es probarlo completamente primero gracias.

Comment: Esta bien @RiouroSatsumoto

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiarle el color de fondo a un Button debes hacer algo asi

```
Button myButton  = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MyButton);

MyButton.setBackgroundColor(0xFF00FF00);
```

puedes jugar tambien asi

```
MyButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
```